# Convering complex type of XML

Tags: xml, wordpress

Im new in work with XML so i really need your help.
I have some XML database and i need to use it in wordpress page. Its not problem to me to convert XML as database but there is one little problem. Images and categories of each products are coded as ´main = "1"´ and ´main = "0"´.

```
 <images>
  <image main="1" link="http://www.link.com/1112/binary.jpg" /> 
  <image main="0" link="http://www.link.com/445/binary.jpg" /> 
  <image main="0" link="http://www.link.com/509/binary.jpg" /> 
  </images>
```

My problem is, that i dont know how to convert this type into database. Other types are simple as name of the product between  etc... So dont you know how to convert this images to be somehow better to work with? Whole XML has about 16000 rows, so its apparent that i cant do it manualy.

Comment: I think there is always exactly one image per record with with main="1". You can see it as the main picture and handle it as featured image.

Comment: Yes, if its main picture, it means that picture was used to be main and the others was just another pictures but also used. I just need to convert this XML to simple database and work with that in wordpress or at least in PHPMyAdmin. I can convert almost everything from XML but images and categories where is used this main, i cant get out of that

Comment: How you convert the other things?

Comment: By parsing in PHP or (easiest way for my needs) by plugin in wordpress. If you know some better way, feel free to teach me :D because i have really no expirience with XML.

Comment: My approach would be parse XML with [PHP](http://php.net/manual/de/simplexml.examples-basic.php) and import the data with [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/).